# View unstaged diff from git interactive add

Tags: git

I'm using Git add's interactive mode (`git add -i`) for the first time and have a question about the `diff` command it offers. By default, it shows a diff for changes I've already staged (equivalent to using `git diff --staged`). Is there a way to make it show a diff of unstaged changes? This would be really helpful for when I need to selectively add some files for staging and want to see the changes I made before adding them. I would like to do this without leaving interactive mode or having another terminal open to do a regular `git diff`.

Comment: Yes, I too have the habit of checking the diff before adding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `git add -p` or the `patch` option of `git add -i` you see the individual changed hunks before you decide whether to stage them or not. You can also change between the unstaged hunks of a file before deciding whether to stage hunks or not.